# How to calculate the size of dataframe in bytes in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, size, spark-streaming

I want to write one large sized dataframe with repartition, so I want to calculate number of repartition for my source dataframe.

```
numberofpartition = {size of dataframe/default_blocksize}
```

How to calculate the dataframe size in bytes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using`spark.sessionState.executePlan(df.queryExecution.logical).optimizedPlan.stats(spark.sessionState.conf).sizeInBytes` we can get the size of actual Dataframe once its loaded into memory. Check the below code.

```
scala> val df = spark.read.format("orc").load("/tmp/srinivas/")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [channelGrouping: string, clientId: string ... 75 more fields]

scala> import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

scala> val bytes = spark.sessionState.executePlan(df.queryExecution.logical).optimizedPlan.stats(spark.sessionState.conf).sizeInBytes
bytes: BigInt = 763275709

scala> FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(bytes.toLong)
res5: String = 727 MB

scala> import sys.process._
import sys.process._

scala> "hdfs dfs -ls -h /tmp/srinivas/".!
Found 2 items
-rw-r-----   3 svcmxns hdfs          0 2020-04-20 01:46 /tmp/srinivas/_SUCCESS
-rw-r-----   3 svcmxns hdfs    727.4 M 2020-04-20 01:46 /tmp/srinivas/part-00000-9d0b72ea-f617-4092-ae27-d36400c17917-c000.snappy.orc
res6: Int = 0
```

```
val bytes = spark.sessionState.executePlan(df.queryExecution.logical).optimizedPlan.stats(spark.sessionState.conf).sizeInBytes
    val dataSize = bytes.toLong
    val numPartitions = (bytes.toLong./(1024.0)./(1024.0)./(10240)).ceil.toInt // May be you can change or modify this to get required partitions.

    df.repartition(if(numPartitions == 0) 1 else numPartitions)
      .[...]
```

`Edit - 1` : Please use the following logic as per your Spark versions.

**Spark 3.0.2**

```scala
val bytes = spark.sessionState.executePlan(df.queryExecution.logical).optimizedPlan.stats.sizeInBytes
```

**Spark 2.4**

```scala
val bytes = spark.sessionState.executePlan(df.queryExecution.logical).optimizedPlan.stats(spark.sessionState.conf).sizeInBytes
```

**Spark 2.3**

```scala
val bytes = spark.sessionState.executePlan(df.queryExecution.logical).optimizedPlan.stats.sizeInBytes
```

**PySpark**

```py
spark._jsparkSession.sessionState().executePlan(df._jdf.queryExecution().logical()).optimizedPlan().stats().sizeInBytes()
```

Comment: For me, this instruction: `spark.sessionState.executePlan(df.queryExecution.logical).optimizedPlan.stats.sizeInBytes`, returns a too big number for a little dataset: `Statistics(sizeInBytes=8.11E+236 B, hints=none)`... Any hint/suggestion? Thank you

Comment: @FernandoAspiazu, Facing the same issue, asked a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63845465/dataset-size-with-optimized-plan-is-returning-way-too-big-number . If you found any solution please answer in that post.

Comment: Why 1024 in this line val numPartitions = (bytes.toLong./(1024.0)./(1024.0)./(10240)).ceil.toInt? How do you select those numbers?

Comment: In my case I have very big files .. more than GB.. I have converted 1GB to bytes..that why you are seeing 1024/1024/1024

Comment: i got the same error. Are you solution, @FernandoAspiazu?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Unfortunately there would not have any solution for the calculation of a DataFrame, this for its Lazy nature... You are forced to calculate the data before in order to have an idea of the dimension such a DF could have, principally for aggregated data that it's calculated in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the late update.

Unfortunately there would not be any solution for the calculation of a DataFrame before it is calculated, for its **Lazy nature**...

You are forced to calculate the data **before** and write it somewhere (In HDFS or any other FS obviously) in order to have an idea of the dimension such a DF could have, mainly for aggregated data that it's calculated in memory.

This could work for data (mostly raw) that are already persisted in the FileSystem, but not for a result from a query that can change the dimension of a dataset.

For example: You can run an aggregation on 1TB of data and get back some GBs as a result, but we're not able to know how many GBs that dataset will have. We have to run it :(

By the way if someone is able to refute what I'm saying here is kindly welcome :)

Cheers.