# Is there a way to make spark re-partition by size rather than count of the data

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, skew

I have a Dataset is evenly divided by record count per partition but some of the partitions have a data size  that is 4 or more times larger than the other ones. Each record has a collection and I imagine could be much larger in some records. This causes what it looks like a data skew some of partitions take a lot longer due to this unbalanced records.
If I could enable some logging in Spark to print the size in bytes of each partition being process and size of the row that could help me in troubleshooting. Because the data is being sent to Cassandra using their Spark connector which is doing some re-partition of their own.

[image]

Comment: Please check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61338374/how-to-calculate-size-of-dataframe-in-spark-scala/61338455#61338455

Comment: I am already repartitoning and they come with pretty much the same record count. I think since rows contain arrays the difference can be large. your link seems to indicate perhaps I could at least log the size or each partition or row while spark is running. That will be helpful to troubleshoot this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to re-partition a dataset by size. In my case I had an array for which some of the rows will have a very large amount of entries. This turnout to be an anomaly on the data and I was able to filter out those rows by simply adding a filter to the dataset.

```
df.filter( size($colname) < 1000)
```