# Parquet data size calculation from Spark Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet, cloudera-cdh

Is there a way to calculate/estimate what the dimension of a Parquet file would be, starting from a Spark Dataset?

For example, I would need a stuff like the following:

```
// This dataset would have 1GB of data, for example
val dataset: DataFrame = spark.table("users")

// I expect that `parquetSize` is 10MB.
val parquetSize: Long = ParquetSizeCalculator.from(dataset)
```

So, I need to know what would be the size of a parquet file given a spark dataset. If there's no code/library over there, I would appreciate an advice of how to calculate it by myself.

I hope I made the question clear :-)

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61338374/how-to-calculate-size-of-dataframe-in-spark-scala/61338455#61338455

Comment: Hi Srinivas, thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately it's not working very well. For the same queryExecution, this code: `spark.sessionState.executePlan(df.queryExecution.logical).optimizedPlan.stats.sizeInBytes` is returning a too large number for a DataFrame with 25K rows: `Statistics(sizeInBytes=8.11E+236 B, hints=none)`

Comment: what is your table size ?? I think it has more than 8 or 80GB of data .. is it correct ?

Comment: No, my table size is 25K, I had to cache DataFrame before launch data size calculation in order to have consistent results. Could you confirm that cache is mandatory for this purpose? Thank you

Comment: cache is not required. check without cache & how much you size you are getting ??

Comment: `scala> val df = spark.table("schema.my_table")`
`scala> spark.sessionState.executePlan(df.queryExecution.logical).optimizedPlan.stats.sizeInBytes`
`res0: BigInt = 9223372036854775807`

`scala> df.cache().count()`
`20/07/24 09:54:20 WARN util.Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.`
`res1: Long = 24217`

`scala> spark.sessionState.executePlan(df.queryExecution.logical).optimizedPlan.stats.sizeInBytes`
`res2: BigInt = 15175573`

Comment: Sorry for the format, could you copy/paste in some editor and see better what the results I'm obtaining.

Comment: `scala> import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

scala> val bytes = spark.sessionState.executePlan(movfatt.queryExecution.logical).optimizedPlan.stats.sizeInBytes
bytes: BigInt = 15175573

scala> FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(bytes.toLong)
res3: String = 14 MB`

Comment: check the size of your data in hdfs

Comment: From HDFS: Disk space consumed: 3.5399 MB, Bytes used: 1.1800 MB

Comment: not that .. check size of hdfs directory for this hive - schema.my_table

Comment: For schema.my_table the size of hdfs directory is that :-D Disk space consumed: 3.5399 MB, Bytes used: 1.1800 MB..... Inconsistent values

Comment: how are you checking that, can you show command ??

Comment: hadoop fs -du -s -h /user/hive/warehouse/schema.db/my_table ===> 1.2 M  3.5 M  /user/hive/warehouse/schema.db/my_table

Comment: now i have got it.. that logic only works on the data which is in memory.. thats why you are getting correct result for cache data.

Comment: Ok, but for data in memory I'm having a too big data size, look at the first comment for this post. `spark.sessionState.executePlan(df.queryExecution.logical).optimizedPlan.stats.sizeInBytes` ======> `Statistics(sizeInBytes=8.11E+236 B, hints=none)`. The reason could be because it's based on queryExecution, the mine is a bit complex and more tables are involved.