# How can i write data into parquet file based on the file size?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have data of 5 GB which i have to write it to the parquet file.Now my question is how to write 1GB data for each parquet file(i.e.I want 5 parquet files for 5GB data).

Comment: Updated link you can check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61338374/how-to-calculate-size-of-dataframe-in-spark-scala/61338455#61338455

Comment: spark version is 2.4

Comment: repartition will not split the file based on size right..Like i want to make the file size default to 1GB even if i am getting 10GB of data i want 10 files

Comment: yes, repartition will split the file based on size if you follow steps in that link. in that link, first we are getting complete size of the data & then dividing that size into number of partitions so that each partition will have approx equal size.

Comment: You may not get exact size of 1 GB .. it may change size little more or less.

Comment: that is fine like i want it to be dynamic and not static..since i donot know the size of the data..like when the parquet reached a specific size i need the data to go into another file

Comment: Size will be calculated dynamic .. only thing is you just have to pass how much of size each partition should have..

Comment: Ok thank you...I hope it should work for me