# Split a large csv into multiple csv with spark

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to write a large data frame (150 go) in hdfs with spark. so I did:

```
df.coalesce(10).write.option("header",true).option("delimiter",";").csv("hdfsPath")
```

I'm expecting to get  as an output 10 partionned csv of 15 go for each
but I got a single csv file containg all data, I figured out that coalesce doesnt work.
Any idea to solve this ?

Comment: Have you tried `repartition()`?

Comment: what is the actual partition count on the Dataframe variable df? If they are less than 10 then coalesce wont do anything. In that case you might have to use repartition.

Comment: Did spark repartition split csv files by line or by bloc size ? in other words, would I have truncated file in output ?

Comment: Check this post for splitting large file into multiple files - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61338374/how-to-calculate-size-of-dataframe-in-spark-scala/61338455#61338455

Answer (score 1):

Quoting after Spark docs for `coalesce`:

> If a larger number of partitions is requested, it will stay at the current number of partitions.

You need to use `repartition` as nehaev suggested.

Comment: Did  spark  repartition  split  csv files by line or by bloc size ?  in other words, would I have truncated file in output ?