# How to optimise the spark repartition or coalesce?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**case 1**

While running spark job and trying to write a data frame as a table , the table is creating around 600 small file (around 800 kb each) - the job is taking around 20 minutes to run

```
df.write.format("parquet").saveAsTable(outputTableName)
```

**case 2**

to avoid the small file if we use coalesce(1)

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("parquet").saveAsTable(outputTableName)
```

now the job will take around - 15 hours to complete

**case 3**

coalesce(10) - job will take 1.5 hours

```
df.coalesce(10).write.format("parquet").saveAsTable(outputTableName)
```

How to find number of partitions are optimum?

Comment: Check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61338374/how-to-calculate-size-of-dataframe-in-spark-scala/61338455#61338455

Comment: zen question: look at the window you have and competition from other resources as well