# How to optimally decides the number of partition in dataframe dynamically?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, partition

I have two dataframes of around 11 million records .After transformation and some window analytic function I am having around 7 million records .I am currently trying to find a dynamic way to calculate  the number of partition .Normally I take the size of dataframe from the ui and then divide it by 256mb (Partition Bytes which is by default 128) and decide the no of partition .I want to avoid this manual steps and like to know if there is any other dynamic and programmatic  way of doing the same .Any help on this will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: if you know the size of a record and the number of records, then you should be able to calculate the size of the dataframe?

Comment: @mck Does it mean I can take help of size estimator to get the size .Because I canot go to ui to get the size .

Comment: I guess so, just estimate the size of `df.limit(1)` and that will give you the size of a record

Comment: Thanks it make sense not pass whole df

Comment: check if this post helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61338374/how-to-calculate-size-of-dataframe-in-spark-scala/61338455#61338455

Comment: You can also estimate the size of a row by `df.schema.defaultSize`